# Not using the Comparable interface in the right way

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparable

Been looking for an answer to this but it seems like my problem is more specific than others.

So i have two classes and one interface. The interface is called "Comparable" and i know that the interface does have its own method, but we will get to that in a sec.

What i have is the classes called "cityMain", "City2" and the interface "Comparable"

What my program is doing right now is that it reads from a txt file with something like:

75242;Uppsala
90325;Umeå
96133;Boden
23642;Höllviken
35243;Växjö
51000;Jönköping
72211;Västerås
etc

The semicolon gets away and the integers and strings split into two.
The numbers are zip codes and well the thing next to it is just a name of some states in sweden. After reading it from the "mainCity" i am actually sorting it so that the top zip with it's name gets to be at the top, so from the least number to the largest.

Then when it gets to read it, it goes to the "City2" class and from there it just goes by every method, one zip and one state at the time.

HOWEVER: Atm i am actually calling everything from my main and NOT from my interface.

It should go like this "mainCity" --> "Comparable" --> "City2". 
The program works as it is but i want it to be correct!

I have tried to go from the "Comparable" and then call it like that but it didn't work nor did it give me an error.
Note, again: That Comparable does has its own method but i have not used it due to the fact that i wouldn't know of how to apply it as it looks right now.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;


public class cityMain {

private static BufferedReader r;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int Z = 0;
    String C = null;
    try {
        ArrayList<City2> City = new ArrayList<City2>();

        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\BB.dat");
        r = new BufferedReader(file);
        String currLine;
        while ((currLine = r.readLine()) != null) {

            if (currLine.trim().length() > 0) {
                String[] split = currLine.split(";");
                Z = (Integer.parseInt(split[0]));
                C = (split[1]);
                City.add(new City2(Z, C));
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(City, (c1, c2) -> c1.getZipCode() - c2.getZipCode());

        for (int i = 0; i < City.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(City.get(i).getZipCode() + " " + City.get(i).getCityName());

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Erorr : " + e);
    }

}

}


HERE IS A DIFFERENT CLASS:

public class City2 implements Comparable {

private int zipCode;
private String cityName;

public City2(int zipCode, String cityName) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
    this.cityName = cityName;
}

public int getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}

public String getCityName() {
    return cityName;
}

public void addAndPrint() {

}

}

HERE IS THE INTERFACE:

public interface Comparable {

public int getZipCode();

public String getCityName();

public void addAndPrint(); 

}
```

What i should get, which i already do get but not in the way that i am supposed to do it!

23642 Höllviken
35243 Växjö
51000 Jönköping
72211 Västerås
75242 Uppsala
90325 Umeå
96133 Boden

Anything would be greatly appreciated right now!

Comment: why did you create your own Comparable interface?

Comment: Because i am not used to using interfaces and i thought that it was the way to do it.... :/

Comment: delete the interface you created, and use the one that Java already provides. if you implement that interface correctly, it'll work as you want

Comment: I feel like the noob king of java right now..

Comment: Yeah but that was about reading and sorting. Now i just need to know of how to implement the Comparable and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you explicitly require to use the `Comparable` interface then change your `City2` class to :

```
public class City2 implements Comparable<City2> {

    private int zipCode;
    private String cityName;

    public City2(int zipCode, String cityName) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public int getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void addAndPrint() {

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(City2 city) {
        return this.getZipCode() - city.getZipCode();
    }

}
```

Observe that :

1. Here we are implementing the `Comparable<City2>` rather than the raw
   type `Comparable`
2. Overriding the `compareTo()` to compare zip-codes as required.
3. There is no need for you to explicitly create an interface
   `Comparable`, but instead just implement the one java provides.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use Java standard library sorting you need to use standard interfaces. You need either collection elements to implement [`java.lang.Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or a separate [`java.lang.Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) object.

It would be best to delete or rename your own version of `Comparator`, it makes unclear which one is actually used when looking at your code because `java.lang` classes are imported automatically.

You have already created a `java.lang.Comparator` with below `(c1, c2)` lambda:

```
Collections.sort(City, (c1, c2) -> c1.getZipCode() - c2.getZipCode());
```

although you could have written it also as:

```
Collections.sort(City, Comparator.comparingInt(City2::getZipCode));
```

Or using [`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)):

```
City.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(City2::getZipCode));
```

Comment: Well i see but how would i add this in the City class which has Comparable as a method? I deleted the interface and then the method from Comparable came up. My assignment says that i still need to use it... :/

Comment: @AxwellSmith implement the method as per `Comparable` interface rules, by comparing the method argument to `this`. It could be as simple as `return this.zipCode - other.zipCode;`. Afterwards it's just `Collections.sort(City);`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so...

Now it is almost 100% Complete!

But i am getting the same answer over and over again...

Ideas?
It is like the prints repeat but the last lines are actually correct....

Main class:
    public class cityMain

```
private static BufferedReader r;
public static ArrayList<City2> City = new ArrayList<City2>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int Z = 0;
    String C = null;
    try {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\karwa\\Desktop\\BB.dat");
        r = new BufferedReader(file);
        String currLine;
        while ((currLine = r.readLine()) != null) {
            City.sort(Comparator.comparing(City2::getZipCode));
            if (currLine.trim().length() > 0) {
                String[] split = currLine.split(";");
                Z = (Integer.parseInt(split[0]));
                C = (split[1]);
                City2 d = new City2(Z, C);
                City.add(d);
                d.print();
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Erorr : " + e);
    }

}
```

Second class:

```
class City2 implements Comparable<City2> {

private int zipCode;
private String cityName;

public City2(int zipCode, String cityName) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
    this.cityName = cityName;
}

public int getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}

public String getCityName() {
    return cityName;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(City2 city) {
    return this.getZipCode() - city.getZipCode();
}

public void print() {

    for (int i = 0; i < cityMain.City.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(cityMain.City.get(i).getZipCode() + " " + cityMain.City.get(i).getCityName());
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Err, any reason you are posting an answer as well? That's not a problem, but it includes another question :)

Comment: Np. But if you see why my code is printing like 20 lines but only gives me the correct lines in the end then please let me know xd.

Comment: That's a simple one. Perform the sorting *after* you have added all elements to the list not while reading the file. Sort the list outside the `while-loop`.

Comment: Why are you using `print()`? Also where are you printing out the list?

Comment: Because i want to print the results? Also my assignment wants me to do so.. In the City Class is where i print everything out. Should i just print it in main?

Comment: I believe you need to print out the list not every object that you put into the list. No need to include the `print()` inside the `City2` class, instead just print out the list. `list.forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Well i see... but as soon as i print in the main method outside of the while loop then everything looks fine... o_0 this is odd to me xD

Comment: Its pretty simple actually. Just that you have mixed up a couple of things! :) Also it isn't required to include an answer if it contains another question.